# Need to check selected is presented and accordingly keys need to filter out

Tags: javascript

I need to access key from below javascript object on the basis of selected. May I know how to access key?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the screenshot as a text rather than an image, helps to reproduce the Map.

Comment: It seems like `Map` object, try `this.assignFilter.filterApply.get('requestAssetClasses')`, here is [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @Livio Thanks for your help. but I need key instead of value.

Comment: I have updated the question (image). I need only key value so how can we access that?

Comment: `[...this.assignFilter.filterApply.keys()]` will give you an array of all the keys

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this, check this out:

```
let map = new Map();
map.set('requestAssetClass', [{"requestAccessClass": ['FX']}]);
let obj = map.get('requestAssetClass')[0];
for (key in obj) {console.log(key, obj[key][0])};
```

Works fine on console.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is there any way we can access key instead of hardcoded (requestAssetsClass)?

Comment: `[...map.keys()]` will give you an array of all the keys